# How to connect to Active Directory with Principal Context?

Tags: c#, active-directory, principalcontext

I've been at this for a while and I'm always getting:

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException

Which I think means my connection setup(connection string) is wrong.

When I write "dsquery server" on cmd on the computer where the Active Directory is I get:

> "CN=DCESTAGIO,CN=SERVERS,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=estagioit,DC=local"

I've tried the following connecting in the following ways:

1:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.56.101", "DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

2:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.56.101/DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

3:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.56.101/CN=DCESTAGIO,DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

4:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.56.101/CN=DCESTAGIO,CN=SERVERS,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

5:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://192.168.56.101/CN=Users,DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

And some other ways...

Any ideas on what's wrong and how I can make this connection work?

PS: The ip is correct seen as I've used it to ping and it's working.

PPS: I really, really need this working ASAP if you have any suggestions at all they're all welcome.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `PrincipalContext` constructors, it should be quite clear:

```
public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name)
```

or

```
public PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name, string container)
```

So you basically need:

- your context type (here: `ContextType.Domain`)
- the domain name (try just the "Netbios" name, e.g. "YOURDOMAIN" - or leave NULL for "default" domain)
- optionally a container (as an LDAP path - a "distinguished" name, full path but without any `LDAP://` prefix)

So try something like this:

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ESTAGIOIT");
```

or

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);  // default domain
```

or

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ESTAGIOIT", "DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

or

```
PrincipalContext thisPrincipalContext = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "CN=Users,DC=estagioit,DC=local");
```

Comment: I have a relevant question. I hope you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971315/finding-active-directory-users-from-2-ou