# Connect to LDAP server using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

We have following server details:

```
Server: CN=HQITSA01,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=example,DC=net
```

We don't have username and password.

Our Code:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "example.net");
```

We have tried above code to connect but it throwing error: The server could not be contacted.

Answer (score 1):

The right instruction should be:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "EXAMPLE", "DC=EXAMPLE,DC=net");
```

where *EXAMPLE* here is the NETBIOS name for the domain. You can also try with

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);
```

to connect to the current domain, if example.net is you current domain.

Check the documentation of `PrincipalContext` object at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) for further details or this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608353/how-to-connect-to-active-directory-with-principal-context).

BTW, "the server could not be contacted" looks like a simple connectivity problem.