# Finding Active Directory users from 2 OU

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a .Net application that reads user from active directory that is in a specific OU (ABCUsers). The following is the code:

```
string DomainIP = "some domain IP";
string ContainerConnectionString = "OU=ABCUsers,DC=test,DC=com";
PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainIP, ContainerConnectionString, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);

PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
UserPrincipal findUser = new UserPrincipal(domain);
findUser.SamAccountName = "some username";
searcher.QueryFilter = findUser;
UserPrincipal foundUser = (UserPrincipal)searcher.FindOne();
```

The above code works fine, but I need to change the code so that it retrieves a user whether he/she is in OU=ABCUsers or OU=XYZUsers but not in any other OU.

Comment: added the loop/function solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(update: reading it again)*

## function/loop solution

*(I would nevertheless prefer the solution with the *Global Catalog* below, because it is much less code and more robust.)*

Since it would probably not work with an `OR`-LDAP-search string when not using the *Global Catalog* as explained below, you could just kind of repeat the above (I guess working) code for the two *OU*s similar to this when put e.g. in a separate function (pseudo code):

```
UserPrincipal findUserInOu( String ou ) {
   string DomainIP = "some domain IP";
   string ContainerConnectionString = "OU=" + ou + ",DC=test,DC=com";
   // ... above code continued
}

UserPrincipal foundUser = findUserInOu("ABCUsers");
if ( foundUser == null )
  foundUser = findUserInOu("XYZUsers");
```

---

## *GlobalCatalog* solution

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044146/1915920), to do it with some `OR`-search string etc. did not work for me and it seems, you may have to use the *Global Catalog* service (on the default **port 3268**, if you have a `MS Active Directory` otherwise I don't know if other directory services would have this feature).
I guess you would have to specify this on the `PrincipalContext` which may use some other default (389?).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will consider this as an answer because it might help someone, but what I was looking for was doing it without having to loop/repeat. Thanks